# Wrap grid ItemHeight binding in windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

i am working with wrap grid in **Listview ItemsPanel** property and i make a **WrapGrid** in it. the question is now can  we bind the **ItemHeight** propety of **WrapGrid** beacause i am not able to do it. i have defined my WrapGrid Like this. and other combinations too.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel >
      <ItemsPanelTemplate >
           <WrapGrid   Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,10" ItemHeight="{Binding Path=ItemHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"  />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

i am able to bind the **DataTemplate** fields of Listview Correctly. i have made the **ItemHeight** property in my CollectionOFItems where all property is defined. so my question is can we bind ItemHeight property if yes please help me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext of your wrap grid is the same as the DataContext of you ListView and not the same as the DataContext of inside the ItemTemplate (so you cannot bind it to a property of an item (the ItemHeight apply to all Items and is not distinct for each item)). To bind it, `ItemHeight="{Binding Path=ItemHeight}"`  will work if ItemHeight is a property of whatever is the DataContext of your ListView (probably your viewModel).

Comment: if you mean you want to bind a different height for each item, no it's not possible. All the items of a WrapGrid have the same height. If you want a panel with variable size height for each item you will need to use a wrap panel (there is one in the WinRTXamlToolkit for example)